# Google Sheets pivot table add column for value with no data

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table, calculated-field

I have survey data on teacher quality with possible responses being 1-4. No one reported 1, so it won't automatically show in the pivot table I am trying to create.

[This](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1i01k5iQzLKo1LrRUc23BE7SM8kQf600xW7x-xLsEavc/edit?usp=sharing) is what I'm working with. Again, I want to add a "1" column, and it should display 0% or a blank cell.

I have looked into calculated fields and messed around with functions and also dummy variables (an additional column listing 1-4 to insert into the pivot table), but I haven't been able to crack the code myself.

Answer (score 1):

***Alternatively** you could try a formula-based approach for your ideal output scenario:*

```js
=let(Σ,sequence(1,4), Λ,A2:A,
     arrayformula({Σ;to_percent(countif(Λ,Σ)/counta(Λ))}))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In order to include zero values in the pivot table, create results that can be included in the pivot table.

**DATA**

- **Column A & B are unchanged**
- **Column C Cell C2** :

  - `=countif($A$2:$A$16,"="&B2)/COUNT($A$2:$A$16)`
  - copy down to cell C3, C4 and C5

**PIVOT TABLE**

- Select B1:C5
- Format as per image below, including manual edits

---

**SAMPLE DATA**

[image: sample data]

**PIVOT TABLE EDITOR**

[image: pivotTableEditor]